# My app is not installing in signed apk mode

Tags: android

I have developed a android application . which is about maintaining the house . i have work with firebase in that application. now the problem is when i install that app in my android phone via usb cable from android studio it's run perfectly. but if i want share the app with someone via share it it's not working. (app not installed)  [image: itsh show something like that]a error come, why . ?? even if i am generate signed apk from android studio then it's also showing the same error . why ? any solution please.

and here the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sonalirod.alwayswhite">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/lastfinalw"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/lastfinalw"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Firstscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Login" />
        <activity android:name=".Interface" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Bazar_Data_Input" />
        <activity android:name=".MealEntry" />
        <activity android:name=".Suggestion" />
        <activity android:name=".admininterface" />
        <activity android:name=".ALogin" />
        <activity android:name=".AdminloginEnter" />
        <activity android:name=".Showalldeposit"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

gradle settings

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sonalirod.alwayswhite"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

and i am trying to install in android 4.4.2 (api 19-20)

Comment: You should share the details of your error, and tell us exactly how you are distributing this package.

Comment: how can i check the error. its fine with runing on emulator . but while i am try  to install that app in my phone via generate apk then its not installing .

Comment: What type of signing you use? V1? V2? Both?

Comment: nop i just only use v2 . that's the problem .

Comment: please check your phone storage. because if your phone insufficient space then app reflect this error.

Answer (score 3):

CommonsWare explained it all.

```
https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html
```

Comment: removing android:testOnly="true" from the AndroidManifest.xml works. This gets added when a new project is created.

Answer (score 0):

Distributing APKs outside of GooglePlay to users need then to accept installing from Unknow Sources.

This options is under Settings > Security.. "Unknow sources"

Based in the link form other answer:
"
    Android Studio 3.0 sets android:testOnly="true" on APKs that are run from the IDE

For many developers, this is of little consequence. However, if you have ever taken an APK lying around your build/ directory and sent it to somebody, that will only work if you did something other than run the app in Android Studio in order to create that APK, such as:

- Built the app using the “Build APK(s)” menu option
- Built the app using the assembleDebug or assembleRelease Gradle tasks
- Built the app using something else that might use those tasks, such as a CI server
  "

Are you building the application as release right?

Comment: it's positive on there . but still now i am not able to install that application. should i need to do something in manifest

Comment: Are you sure are targeting the other phone SDK or lower?